# Magento 2.3 Wishlist API free extension needed

Tags: magento2, api, wishlist

This is continuation for the following closed question:

[Magento 2.3 Wishlist API free extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326657/magento-2-3-wishlist-api-free-extension)

As you can see I extremely sad about some god that closed a good question.

Well let us go again...

---

I need to add, and remove products from a client's wishlist via Magento REST API. But Magento 2 core code does not have it.

... Anyone can help me with free wishlist API extensions compatible with Magento 2.3 ?

I could make this by my own but it take me a couple of days coding....

Thanks.... and electricity binary bits empowered god I praise please don't close good questions again lol...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this commit https://github.com/manish-ip/magento2/commit/0b6127dcd39045d0aa8d119dfdd30a0b89eba2df. Use these files to create a new module but change the module namespace to something like `\Magento\WishlistApi` (or whatever you like really). They have also released this as a module on the Magento marketplace for $25 https://marketplace.magento.com/ipragmatech-module-ipwishlist.html if you prefer a pre-built module.

I have published a module at that can be downloaded and installed for free. To install run `composer require newbury/module-wishlist-api` (https://github.com/cjnewbs/module-wishlist-api). I have also submitted it to the Magento Marketplace.

Comment: Great idea :) I had seen the module but the idea is so simple that it didn't seem right charging for the module.

Comment: If you don't need it for a day or 2 I am actually working on a module from scratch to provide full (working with configurable and bundle products for example) wishlist functionality via the API. It does seem crazy there isn't a module for it. I will be releasing it via GitHub, Packagist and the Magento Marketplace. When I publish it I'll update my answer with a link to each location.

Comment: I am a Magento developer, if you need help to get it faster let me know and we can work together on a git.

Comment: @GustavoUlyssea Answer updated with free module on Packagist & GitHub